# Spectral density of a sample covariance matrix in a Gaussian Random Ensemble

Tags: integration

Let $N > 0$ and $T > N$ be integers and $C$ be a real, symmetric $N \times N$ matrix.The question is to compute the following integral:
\begin{equation}
U_{N,T}(t) := \frac{1}{N} \int\limits_{{\mathcal R}^{N T}}Tr\left[e^{\frac{\imath t}{T} {\bf X} \cdot {\bf X}^T}\right] e^{-\frac{1}{2} Tr\left[C^{-1} {\bf X} \cdot {\bf X}^T\right]} \frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^N \prod\limits_{\xi=1}^T d X_{i,\xi}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{N T} \left(\det(C)\right)^T}}
\end{equation}
Here ${\bf X} := \left(X_{i\xi}\right)_{i=1,\xi=1}^{N,T}$. This integral is equal to the Fourier transform of the spectral density of the sample covariance matrix in a Gaussian random ensemble. I know that there exists a series expansion in terms of spectral moments of the matrix $C$ for this integral. Yet, I would like to know if there is some closed form expression for that integral.

Comment: you mean inverse Fourier transform? Why would I Fourier transform a spectral density again?

Comment: The spectral density of the sample covariance matrix is defined as \begin{equation} \rho(\lambda) := \frac{1}{N} \left<Tr\left[\delta\left(\lambda - \frac{1}{T} {\bf X} \cdot {\bf X}^T\right) \right]\right>\end{equation} If you take the Fourier transform with respect to $\lambda$ you end up with the multivariate integral above.  The multivariate Gaussian integral above is definitely easier to calculate than the spectral density itself.

Answer (score 1):

I present a solution in case of $N=2$. 
Note,  that the integrand is a function of the matrix elements of the sample covariance matrix only. Therefore we will reduce the $(N\cdot T)$-dimensional integral to a  $N(N+1)/2$-dimensional integral over the elements of the  sample covariance matrix.
We insert the obvious identity:
\begin{equation}
1 = \int\limits_{{\mathcal R} \times {\mathcal R}_+^2} 
\delta\left(c_{1,1} - \sum\limits_{j=1}^T X_{1,j}^2\right)
\delta\left(c_{2,2} - \sum\limits_{j=1}^T X_{2,j}^2\right)
\delta\left(c_{1,2} - \sum\limits_{j=1}^T X_{1,j} X_{2,j}\right)
 d c_{1,2} d c_{1,1} d c_{2,2}
\end{equation}
into the integrand, then we swap the order of integration, ie we integrate over the $X_{i,\xi}$ variables first and we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&U_{N,T}(t) = \\
&&\frac{1}{N} \int\limits_{{\mathcal R} \times {\mathcal R}_+^2}
Tr\left[e^{\frac{\imath t}{T} \left(\begin{array}{cc}c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} \\ c_{1,2} & c_{2,2}\end{array}\right)}\right]
\cdot
{\mathcal A}_T \pi^{T-1} \left(\det(c)\right)^{\frac{T-3}{2}} \cdot
e^{-\frac{1}{2} Tr\left[C^{-1} \left(\begin{array}{cc}c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} \\ c_{1,2} & c_{2,2}\end{array}\right) \right]}
\frac{ d c_{1,2} d c_{1,1} d c_{2,2}}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^{2 T} \left(\det(C)\right)^T}}
\end{eqnarray}
In here we have used the result given in [Multidimensional integral involving delta functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868206/multidimensional-integral-involving-delta-functions/902087#902087) . The constant ${\mathcal A}_T$ reads ${\mathcal A}_T := 2^{T-3}/(T-2)!$. Now, we perform an eigenvalue decomposition of the sample covariance matrix.
\begin{equation}
 \left(\begin{array}{cc}c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} \\ c_{1,2} & c_{2,2}\end{array}\right)
=
O
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
s_1 & 0 \\ 0 & s_2
\end{array}
\right)\cdot O^T
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
O := \left(
\begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
It is easy to show that the Jacobian of the appropriate transformation reads:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\left(c_{1,1},c_{2,2},c_{1,2}\right)}{\partial\left(s_1,s_2,\theta\right)} = s_1-s_2
\end{equation}
Therefore we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&U_{N,T}(t) = \\
&& \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{{\mathcal R}_+^2} \left(e^{\frac{\imath t s_1}{T}} + e^{\frac{\imath t s_2}{T}}\right)
{\mathcal A}_T \pi^{T-1} \left(s_1 s_2\right)^{\frac{T-3}{2}} \left|s_1-s_2\right| \cdot \\
&&\int\limits_0^{2\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2} Tr\left[C^{-1} O 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
s_1 & 0 \\ 0 & s_2
\end{array}
\right)
O^T
\right]}
d \theta \cdot
\frac{d s_1 d s_2}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^{2 T} \left(\det(C)\right)^T}}
\end{eqnarray}
The integral over the angle $\theta$ is the famous Itzykson-Zuber integral over the orthogonal group $O(2)$. Unfortunately there is no closed-form expression in terms of elementary functions, for that integral but the result can be expressed through a Bessel function. So the result is:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&U_{N,T}(t)= \frac{2^{T-2} \pi^{T}}{(T-2)!}  \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{{\mathcal R}_+^2} \left(e^{\frac{\imath t s_1}{T}} + e^{\frac{\imath t s_2}{T}}\right)
\left(s_1 s_2\right)^{\frac{T-3}{2}} \left|s_1-s_2\right| \cdot \\
&&e^{-\frac{1}{4} \frac{C_{1,1}+C_{2,2}}{\det(C)}(s_1+s_2)}
{\mathcal I}_0\left(\frac{1}{4} \frac{\sqrt{(C_{1,1}-C_{2,2})^2 + 4 C_{1,2}^2}}{\det(C)}(s_1-s_2)\right)
\frac{d s_1 d s_2}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^{2 T} \left(\det(C)\right)^T}}
\end{eqnarray}
I do not think that there exists any closed form solution for the integral above and therefore I leave it as it is. Yet, we will see that that result can be readily used to derive spectral moments of the eigenvalue density.
\begin{equation}
m_{p} := \frac{d^p U_{N,T}(t)}{d (\imath t)^p} = \int\limits_0^\infty \lambda^p \rho(\lambda) d\lambda
\end{equation}
for $p=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. We will derive those spectral moments in a future post.

Now, we will compute the spectral moments. We rewrite the double integral over the eigenvalues by absorbing a constant into the $s$-values. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&U_{N,T}(t) = \frac{2^{2 T-3}}{(T-2)!} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\det C}}{Tr C}\right)^T \\
&&\int\limits_{{\mathcal R}_+^2} 
\left(
\sum\limits_{\xi=1}^2  e^{\imath \frac{t}{T} \frac{4 \det C}{Tr C} s_\xi}
\right)
\left(s_1 s_2\right)^{\frac{T-3}{2}}\left|s_1-s_2\right|
{\mathcal I}_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{(C_{1,1}-C_{2,2})^2 + 4 C_{1,2}^2}}{Tr C}(s_1-s_2)\right) e^{-s_1-s_2} d s_1 d s_2
\end{eqnarray}
Now we expand the Bessel function into a power series:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal I}_0(x) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(m!)^2} (\frac{x}{2})^{2 m}
\end{equation}
 about the origin and we integrate term by term over the eigenvalues. In doing that we use the following identity:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_0^\infty \int\limits_0^\infty 
(s_1 s_2)^p \left(s_1^q + s_2^q\right) \left|s_1-s_2\right| (s_2-s_1)^{2 m} e^{-s_1-s_2} d s_1 d s_2 = \\
&&\frac{m!}{2^{2 p+q}} \cdot \frac{(p+q)!(2p+2 m+2+q)!}{(m+p+q+1)!} \cdot
F_{3,2} \left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
1+m & \frac{1+q}{2} & \frac{q}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & 2+m+p+q
\end{array};
1
\right]
\end{eqnarray}
where $p \in {\mathbb R}_+$, $m\in {\mathbb N}$ and $q \ge -p$ and $q \in {\mathbb Z}$.

Now, having integrated over the eigenvalues we end up with an infinite series in $m$. We find a closed form for that series expansion using an identity derived in here [Interesting combinatoral identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911010/interesting-combinatoral-identity) .This gives us a neat closed form expression for the $q$th spectral moment (where $q \ge 0$). For even values of $q$ we  have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&m_{2 q}=
\frac{1}{T^{2q-1}} \sum\limits_{q_1=0}^{q} \left(\frac{2 q}{2 q- q_1}\right) \binom{2 q - q_1}{q_1}  (-1)^{q_1} 
{\mathcal W}^{(2q-1)}\left(T\right)
 \cdot
\left(Tr C\right)^{2q-2 q_1} \left(\det C\right)^{q_1}
\end{eqnarray}
and for odd values of $q$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&m_{2 q+1}=
\frac{1}{T^{2 q}} \sum\limits_{q_1=0}^{q} \left(\frac{2q+1}{2 q+1-q_1}\right) \binom{2 q+1-q_1}{q_1}  (-1)^{q_1} 
{\mathcal W}^{(2 q)}\left(T\right)
 \cdot
\left(Tr C\right)^{2 q+1-2 q_1} \left(\det C\right)^{q_1}
\end{eqnarray}
In both the even and the odd case we have:
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal W}^{(q-1)}\left(T\right) := \sum\limits_{q_1=0}^{q}
\prod\limits_{j=1}^{q-q_1-1} \left(T+ 2 j\right) \cdot
\prod\limits_{j=q-q_1}^{q-1} \left(T+ 2 j-1\right)
\end{equation}
Using Mathematica we have finally checked that the following identities hold:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2} m_0 &=&  1\\
\frac{1}{2} m_1 &=& M_1 \\
\frac{1}{2} m_2 &=& M_2\left(1 + \frac{1}{T}\right) + r M_1^2\\
\frac{1}{2} m_3 &=& M_3\left(1 + \frac{3}{T} + \frac{4}{T^2}\right) + 3 r \left(1+\frac{1}{T}\right) M_2 M_1 + r^2 M_1^3\\
\frac{1}{2} m_4 &=& M_4\left(1+ \frac{6}{T} + \frac{21}{T^2} + \frac{20}{T^3}\right) + 4 r \left(1+\frac{3}{T}+\frac{4}{T^2}\right) M_3 M_1 + r \left(2+\frac{5}{T}+\frac{5}{T^2}\right) M_2^2 + 6 r^2 \left(1+\frac{1}{T}\right) M_2 M_1^2 + r^3 M_1^4
\end{eqnarray}
where $M_p := Tr\left[ C^p \right]/N$ and $r := N/T$. The identities above match-- except for the multiplicative factor $1/2$ on the left hand side -- those known from literature and derived using a diagrammatical method based on Wick's theorem.

Update: Now we derive the negative spectral moments. Take $p\in {\mathbb N}$ and then from the very definition in the body of the question we have:
\begin{equation}
m_{-p} := \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{t^{p-1}}{(p-1)!} \cdot U_{N,T}(\imath t) dt
\end{equation}

Comment: The reference to Wick's theorem at the end makes me grin a bit, since right from the start of this calculation it was reminding me of a field theory calculation (which is where Wick made his major contributions.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: I agree that the wording needs to be brushed up upon  but what I ment is the following. There is a way of computing the spectral moments by expanding the left-most exponential in the definition of the resolvent, in a power series and integrating term by term. In here it is handy to use the Wick-Isserlis' theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem . However using that method there was no way to derive all spectral moments, except under some simplifying assumptions. This is the reason I wanted to go along a different path and obtain all those moments.